# Materialize Cards Not on Equal Height

Tags: materialize

I created a codepen trying to get equal height for the cards, but I was unable to.

The images have different sizes and I added the `responsive-img` tag.

https://codepen.io/jgacuca567/pen/qXwXEz

```
    <main class="container-fluid">
     <section class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m4 l4">
       <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="https://unsplash.it/4579/3271?image=1084" class="responsive-img">
          <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <a href="#">This is a link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m4 l4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="https://unsplash.it/5472/3648?image=1083" class="responsive-img">
          <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <a href="#">This is a link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m4 l4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="https://unsplash.it/5416/3611?image=1082" class="responsive-img">
          <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <a href="#">This is a link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437535/card-image-width-not-equal-when-i-gave-max-height

Answer (score 6):

**Default Materialize sizes**

MaterializeCSS offers three default sizes for cards (small, medium and large).
These can be added like the following: (taken directly from the [docs](http://materializecss.com/cards.html), under the title "Card Sizes".)

```
<div class="card small">
    <!-- Card Content -->
</div>
```

**Custom Height**

If all images need to have the same height, and a fixed height is acceptable, add this to your css:

```
.card-image{
    height: 400px; /* Your height here */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Of course, everyone should read all of the docs, but all else being equal scolding someone discourages others from asking questions.